# Angular secondary route throwing errors

Tags: angular, routes

I have been struggling with this for a while now I cannot get this to navigate to a named route.

I have a container that look like:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="bottom"></router-outlet>
```

And some routes that look like:

```
export const AccountRoutes:Routes = [
// other routes
{path:'address-list', component:AddressesListComponent, outlet:'bottom'}
]
```

and I'm calling this like:

```
this.router.navigate([{outlets:{bottom:['crm','accounts','address-list']}}])
```

When I call this i get an error that says

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'crm/accounts/address-list'

but the funny thing is if i take off the outlet in the route and just navigate like `this.router.navigate(['crm','accounts','address-list'])`
it works.

So can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to figure this out, it did take about a day to do it but here is the answer.

```
this.router.navigate([
               '', 
               'crm',
               'accounts', 
               {
                  outlets:{
                      bottom:'address-list'
                  }
               }]);
```